# How to create woocommerce drop down list for all products

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce

trying to create woocommerce drop down list for all products
here's the code 
thanks in advance

```
<select Name='choose'>
  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
      $loop->the_post();
      echo '<option selected value="'.the_title().'</option>';
  endwhile;
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You should always explain what the code you have provided is doing versus what you expect it to do. What is the problem?

Comment: upload csv data for selected product  by extracting product id for custom db table

Comment: What? I can't see any link between your question, your code, and your comment. Please try to clarify your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong.

Here's the correct way of outputting the options:

`'<option  value="'.the_title('','',false).'">'.the_title('','',false).'</option>'`

Most likely you will need the post id as a the value and not the title itself, but that's besides the point.

`the_title` function by default echoes the result. We just want the value itself in this case. So we pass an empty string for the before and after params and a false for the *echo* param.

You could alternatively use the `get_the_title` function which is a cleaner way of doing the same.

Depending on your scenario, getting the information needed from the post object is more efficient. You would loop through the posts objects after you retrieve them like this: `$loop->get_posts()`

Comment: thanks for your response   for this particular project the product  id is needed as well as  the title, as it needs to be inserted into a custom db table along  with csv upload form .basically upload csv data for selected product